# VBA Outlook Macro to attach a specific file to an outgoing email based on Subject line or Recipient's Last name

Tags: vba, outlook, office365, email-attachments

I'm new to using VBA. I'm looking to see if it's possible to create a macro that will attach a specific file to an outgoing email if there is a partial match with the Subject Line OR depending on the recipient's last name.

For example, if I am drafting an email with the subject line "XYZ-03210 - Case - Date" I'd like to have a macro button that will attach a doc with the file name "XYZ-03210_TEMPLATE"

If that isn't possible, that file is also located in a shared folder named with the Recipient's last name, so the macro could look to find the file based on the last name as well.

Thank you!

Right now I just have a basic macro button that will attach a generic file to an outgoing draft email, but I would like to create a more complex macro that will attach a SPECIFIC file based on the criteria I mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to attach files based on the `Subject` property value to the outgoing items in Outlook. You can try handling the `ItemSend` event of the `Application` class which is fired whenever an Microsoft Outlook item is sent, either by the user through an Inspector (before the inspector is closed, but after the user clicks the Send button) or when the Send method for an Outlook item, such as `MailItem`, is used in a program.

So, in the `ItemSend` event handler you may check the `Subject` property of the Item passed as a parameter and try to attach a file with such name. Use the [Mid function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/mid-function) to get a specified number of characters from a string. For example:

```
Dim MyString, FirstWord, LastWord, MidWords
YourSubject = "Mid Function Demo"    ' Create text string.
MidWords = Mid(MyString, 5)    ' Returns "Function Demo"
```

To attach a file you need to use the [Attachments.Add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.attachments.add) method which creates a new attachment in the `Attachments` collection. The source of the attachment. can be a file (represented by the full file system path with a file name) or an Outlook item that constitutes the attachment. So, if you need to attach a file from a shared folder, you need to copy or move it locally before calling the `Add` method.

Finally, I'd suggest starting from the [Getting started with VBA in Office](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/library-reference/concepts/getting-started-with-vba-in-office) article.